# Reset desktop icons on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, desktop, icons, layout

Few months ago, I played with space parameters (margin) between desktop icons (with TuneUP utilities), then uninstalled this application. Now I want to reset my custom desktop layout to default. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-increase-icon-spacing-in-windows-7/

Answer (score -1):

Right click > Auto arrange icons and/or click refresh.

Comment: LOOOL))). You think this will reset space between icons?

Comment: @TuralTeyyuboglu did you at least try it?